# get different column value from two tables which has same primary key in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, linq-to-sql

I have two tables with same name/schema but with different values.
I need to find the row which has same primary key(1st column) but different values.
ex.
my-table:

```
id   name   age
1    ram    25
2    mohan   30
```

my-table:

```
id  name  age
3   harry  26
**1   ram   35**
3   tony   45
```

So I need 2 row from 2 table with value 35.
It should return whole row as data table or data row.
I am using oracle database. needed c#  code for this solution.
and it should work for multiple column values for other tables also.
my code..

```
public OracleCommand getColumns(OracleConnection connection, DataTable table, int i, string tab, DataTable table3)
{
    int columCount = table.Columns.Count;
    string [] colArray = new string[columCount];
    string pkey = table.Columns[0].ColumnName;
    string pkeyValue = table.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string query2 = "SELECT * FROM " + tab +
                " WHERE " + tab + "." + pkey + " = '" + pkeyValue + "'";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
    int k = 0;
    int  X =0;

    for(int j=1 ; j<colArray.Length;j++)
    {
        string column = table.Columns[j].ColumnName;
        string columnValue = table.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        string add = " OR " + tab + "." + column + " = '" + columnValue + "'";
        query2 += add;
        command.CommandText = query2;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection = connection;
        var check = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (check == null)
        {
            k++;
        }
        else
            X++;   
    }
     return command;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro. i m new here....

Comment: I don't really understand Your Goal - can You clarify Your question ?

Comment: So you want to get a row [1, ram, 25] and a row [1, ram, 35], as the id=1 matches, but the age doesn't?

Comment: So you need something like select id from tab1 t , tab2 w where t.id=w.id ?

Comment: i need to get stared value ..

Comment: @Harry007 what do u mean ?

Comment: So only one row. That is the differing row compared to the first table. Like this?: `select t2.* from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t1.age != t2.age or t1.name != t2.name` So if ID matches but any other value doesn't, then return it from second table.

Comment: sqlcommand i know but how do i implement it in c#

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for your tables, I am presenting data from t2 which do not match rows in t1:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

...

public string OraText(string pkey, string[] tables, string[] columns)
{
    string sSQL = "select " + pkey + "";
    foreach (string s in columns)
    {
        sSQL += ", " + tables[1] + "." + s;
    }
    sSQL += Environment.NewLine + "  from t1 join t2 using (" + pkey + ") "
        + Environment.NewLine + "  where 1=0 ";
    foreach (string s in columns)
    {
        sSQL += " or " + tables[0] + "." + s + " <> " + tables[1] + "." + s;
    }

    return sSQL;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(
        "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=XE");
    oc.Open();

    string[] tables = {"t1", "t2"};
    string[] columns = {"name", "age"};

    string sSQL = OraText("id", tables, columns);
    OracleCommand oracmd = new OracleCommand(sSQL, oc);
    OracleDataReader reader = oracmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0) + " " 
            + reader.GetValue(1) + " " +reader.GetValue(2));
    }

    oc.Close();
}
```

Console output:

```
1 ram 35
```

Comment: both the tables are from different database...but name and structure is same values/row will be different.

Comment: So you have three possibilities: 1) in first database create [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) to second database and join data using this link - in this case you can use my solution (modify `tables` similiar to {`t1, t2@dblink`})  2) gather data from both tables into C# DataTable objects and compare this objects row by row with matching PK's 3) compare DataTable objects using LINQ (I'm not too good at this, but you can search for examples in the net).

Comment: If you have possibility to create link that this solution will be fastest, I would do it this way.